# AWS managed elasticsearch S3 snapshot permissions

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3, aws-elasticsearch

I have an AWS managed Elasticsearch instance (older pre-"OpenSearch" variant).  I want to enable snapshot backups to S3, but I can't seem to get the permissions correct.

I'm trying to use instance roles, not specific user credentials.  I've tried following [this guide](https://medium.com/docsapp-product-and-technology/aws-elasticsearch-manual-snapshot-and-restore-on-aws-s3-7e9783cdaecb) as well as quite a few others that are very similar.

I have a role: arn:aws:iam::MYACCOUNTID:role/`QA-elasticsearch-instance-role`.  That role has the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListS3BackupBucket",
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::MYACCOUNTID:role/QA-elasticsearch-instance-role",
                "arn:aws:s3:::qa-mycompanyname-elasticsearch-backups"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowBackupStorage",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::qa-mycompanyname-elasticsearch-backups/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowElasticSearchPost",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "es:ESHttpPost",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:MYACCOUNTID:domain/qa-elasticsearch"
        }
    ]
}
```

This role also has the following trust relationship:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "es.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have the following python script to try and create the snapshot repository:

```
import boto3
import requests
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth

host = 'https://MYELASTICSEARCHENDPOINT.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/'
region = 'us-east-1' # For example, us-west-1
service = 'es'
credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()

awsauth = AWS4Auth("MYACCESSKEY", "MYSECRETKEY", region, service)

# Register repository
path = '_snapshot/qa_snapshot_repository' # the Elasticsearch API endpoint
url = host + path

payload = {
    "type": "s3",
    "settings": {
        "bucket": "qa-MYCOMPANYNAME-elasticsearch-backups",
        "region": "us-east-1",
        "role_arn": "arn:aws:iam::MYACCOUNTID:role/QA-elasticsearch-instance-role"
    }
}

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

r = requests.put(url, auth=awsauth, json=payload, headers=headers)

print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

When I run this, (`python3 elasticsearch_test.py | jq .`) I get the following:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "repository_verification_exception",
        "reason": "[qa_snapshot_repository] path  is not accessible on master node"
      }
    ],
    "type": "repository_verification_exception",
    "reason": "[qa_snapshot_repository] path  is not accessible on master node",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "i_o_exception",
      "reason": "Unable to upload object [tests-4-VcUFXhTcW4PQ6fi6AiVA/master.dat] using a single upload",
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "amazon_s3_exception",
        "reason": "Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: RJKPNBBEQQBNWHWT; S3 Extended Request ID: 3O5AqSkKhsCNlmYLCtcfnE0omhp6wdbPCejJ2r4dNJq93l2xppSs4Hv6uTGvNIJ2jFWLt31gsyc=)"
      }
    }
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

I've been googling and trying to tweak permissions for a few hours now, but can't seem to get it right.  Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: The [Amazon OpenSearch Service documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/managedomains-snapshots.html#managedomains-snapshot-prerequisites) shows the `iam:PassRole` permission is granted to the IAM user or role used to sign the request. This role is separate from the role that Amazon OpenSearch Service assumes to gain access to the S3 bucket.

Comment: @ChinHuang - OK, thanks.  Sorry for being dense, but what do I do with that information?

I have added the trust relationship for the elasticsearch domain to assume that role, and the role has all relevant permissions to read/write to S3.  I pass that role in to the snapshot repository creation request.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it turns out the error response was super misleading.  It isn't really an "AccessDenied" problem, but rather the request to S3 is getting rejected because of improper encryption between client and server.  Following [this post](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-get-s3-repository-working-with-aws-instance-profile/80380/9) I decided to try adding `"server_side_encryption": "true"`, and everything worked.

```
payload = {
    "type": "s3",
    "settings": {
        "bucket": "qa-mycompanyname-elasticsearch-backups",
        "region": "us-east-1",
        "role_arn": "arn:aws:iam::myaccountid:role/QA-elasticsearch-instance-role",
        "server_side_encryption": "true"
    }
}
```

```
200
{
  "acknowledged": true
}
```

I have no proper explanation for why this worked.  I guess it tells the client on the Elasticsearch instance to use `https` URLs to communicate with S3 instead of `http`, but seems nuts that http would be the default, or that there wouldn't be a better error message back.